# Sourcing script for dygraphs in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, dygraphs

I am trying to use `dygraphs` in a sourced `R` script for generating an HTML page from an `rmarkdown` document.

If I run the following code, I get a nice dygraph in RStudio's viewer.

````
```{r, fig.width=6, fig.height=2.5}
    require(dygraphs)
    g1 <- dygraph(nhtemp, main = "New Haven Temperatures", ylab = "Temp (F)")
print(g1)
```
````

However, if I save the same code in an .R script and use `source()`, no graph gets printed.

````
```{r, fig.width=6, fig.height=2.5}
source(file = '~/myDygaph.R')
```
````

I am trying to find what might be the reason for this:
 1. I checked that using `source()` prints the results using `echo = verbose` and `print.eval = echo`, so I don't think there will be a problem in printing.
 2. `local = FALSE` ensures that parsed expressions are evaluated in the global environment

But so far I haven't succeeded in finding the reason(s)...